# Excessive engine noise and vibration in cabin 09 toyota camry 2.4l

Tags: toyota, noise, camry, vibration

I have had a 2009 toyota camry for about 3 years now and when I was accelerating onto the interstate I heard a loud pop under the car and i think it came from the drivers footwell, that's when I could hear the engine in the cabin. My steering wheel vibrates with my engine. The noise is always there no matter what rpm or gear I am in. I removed the whole exhaust and started it up and still has the same issue. The engine is not any louder than it was before from outside the car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is that an engine mount has broken.  The engine may now be resting against some of the bodywork or other components in the engine bay causing vibrations to be passed into the passenger compartment.